# java.outOfMemory when reading file to bytes

Tags: android

I get an java.outOfMemory Exception when tring to read a 60 mb big file to bytes.
I tried apache i/o commons [IOUtils.toByteArray(fos)] and:

```
        File file = new File(f);
        int size = (int) file.length();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            buf.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bytes;
```

Has anyone an idea how i could read the file to byte[] without an exception?

I want to split the file into 15mb pices, adding a "header"(in byte, containing the own part number) to theme, share them and than, with the information of the "header" I want to re-construcct the original file.

Comment: you are reading a large file into memory and running out of it, sounds like an expected result

Comment: 60 MB file is big but definitely not close to tapping the limits of even a relatively recent computer. Can you post the Exception, and point to the line of code above where it is occurring?

Comment: @JStevenPerry  What on earth do you mean, given that the `BufferedReaderStream` is created on the heap which, on many devices, will have a limit of 64MB or lower?  What does a "recent computer" have to do with this?

Comment: We are always talking about an Android device, not a PC with 16 GB of ram. Anyway, you really need to load the entire file in memory?

Comment: Okay, so 60MB is closer to the 1GB of RAM on the Galaxy S3 than on a typical recent PC. A thousand pardons.

Comment: well, i'm not entierly sure but i think it is nessecary.... I want to splitt it into 15 MB parts and do some kind of crypting with the files. Would it be better to split the file in parts first and than work with them?

Comment: @EricPro edit the question with a more specific definition of the higher level problem you're trying to solve and perhaps someone can suggest a design that doesn't require you to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: @JStevenPerry  You missed the point.  I can install 128GB on my Android device, it still has a limit on the heap of 64MB, if I'm lucky.  Often 32MB or 16MB,  RAM available has nothing do to with how large objects can be.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for educating me without being a complete tool about it. You have a good day now.

Comment: @JStevenPerry  You too.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may read file as String lines [like described here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) and use `String.getBytes()` method to get bytes from each line & later compose them in whatever you want